# How do i create a QR code myself with logo

Tags: qr-code

I want to create a QR-code myself with a logo. Maybe its because I don't know enough about QR codes but I'm scared that if the generator where I created the QR-code gets removed that my QR-code isn't working anymore. So that's why I want to create it myself.

**so my questions are as follows:**

Is it convenient and possible to make a QR code with a logo from scratch without a generator?

Does anyone have a tutorial for this?

Do I not have to worry about using a generator because the QR code continues to work if the generator no longer exists?

Comment: Since you have mentioned 'wothout generator', how you are planning to generate QR Code? Means what platform you are using?

Comment: Yes because every time I see a generator I need to pay for specific options. 
I also don't want to become dependent on a company. So if they are creating them I can do it's myself right? I am also open to other options

Comment: You can use npm package for the same. Check this url https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-code-styling. Good Luck